# Create related tables in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm developing a simple forum app in Ruby on Rails, with MongoDB.

It's supposed to have these basic things:

```
Topics
-Author name
-Topic name
-Topic text (content)
```

and

```
Comments
-Name of commentator 
-Comment text
```

And one should be able to create/edit/delete `Topics` and `Comments`

I'm confused about how to go about the table structure in MongoDB.
I mean, this is what I have in mind if I were to go with MySQL:

Topic:

```
ID - autoincrement int(10)
author - varchar(40)
topic_text - text
```

Comments:

```
ID - autoincrement integer
commentator_name - varchar(40)
comment_text - text
for_topic_id - int(10) //the Topic on which this comment is
```

How do I do it in MongoDB?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

There are no more tables exists in mongodb. When you comes to mongodb it's all collections. Each collection is a collection of documents(rows in Mysql). You can create whatever fields you want on the fly. You have write fields directly in model instead of migrations. For example in your case:

```
class Topic
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :author, type: String
   field :topic_text,  type: String
end
```

When it comes to `id` it generates 24 digit unique BSON id for every document in an increment manner with in a collection

Note: I am using `mongoid` as an ORM to talk with mongoDB from my rails app.